# Understanding matrices that slide all points along functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, linear-transformations, hyperbolic-functions

$H$ is a matrix that defines hyperbolic rotation in the standard form. This essentially means we are sliding all points along the hyperbola by some angle.

$$H=\exp\begin{pmatrix} 0 & s \\ s & 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cosh s & \sinh s \\ \sinh s & \cosh s\end{pmatrix}.$$

Similarly for a rectangular hyperbola $B$ gives the hyperbolic rotation and we are essentially sliding all points along the hyperbola $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}.$ The transformation matrix that achieves this is

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} e^s & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-s}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Given a function like $g(x)=\exp(\frac{1}{\log(x)})$ how can I find the transformation matrix that slides all points along $g?$

I could be wrong but I think it is simply $$R=\exp(A).$$ for $x,g>1.$

Comment: We are not sliding all points along $y=1/x$ because most points are not on this curve, you need a whole family of curves that foliates the plane. You can then take a vector field tangent to these curves, and its [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)) will slide points along them. But except in very special cases this vector field will not be linear in $x,y$, and so not generated by a matrix.

Comment: @Conifold Not sliding all points of the plane, sliding all points of the curve along the curve. (Although, OP: it's not a matrix, it's a one-dimensional family of matrices. In the case of hypoerbolas it will be a one-parameter subgroup, but not in general.)